# Systemctl's restart feature should have killed previous process before running a new one

Tags: linux, centos, systemd, systemctl

Here is my configuration file:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=65535
LimitNPROC=65535
TasksMax=infinity
Type=forking
PIDFile=/data/happybird/happybird.pid
WorkingDirectory=/data/happybird
ExecStart=/data/happybird/bin/happybird
RestartSec=5
Restart=on-failure
```

What I have observed is that after 10 minutes there are 5 happybird processes running
. This line of configuration has started happybird so many times without killing the previous process, how to properly solve this problem?

```
Restart=on-failure
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that my program removed the pid file which confused systemd and
caused systemd to run a "not running" program.